# Icelandic Eth and Thorn for Latex

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Is it possible to produce the Icelandic Eth and Thorn in LaTex? The lower case eth appears in phonetic fonts, but I need the upper case version. It would be good to have Thorn also.

Comment: `\dh \DH \th \TH` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or use a Unicode engine.